# apa citation call-out style in apa7 document class

Tags: citing, apa-style, apacite, apa7

I am using the `apa7` document class in overleaf. However, somehow, `\parencite` always hides all authors but the first one even the first time an entry is cited.

For example, **\parencite{Lassen2006}** returns **(Lassen et al., 2006)**. However, I want it to be **(Lassen, Steele, & Sailor, 2006)** the first time it is cited and then **(Lassen et al., 2006)** for subsequent citations.

Below is the bib file and my header:

```
@ARTICLE{Lassen2006,
  author = {Lassen, Stephen R. and Steele, Michael M. and Sailor, Wayne},
  title = {The relationship of school-wide positive behavior support to academic achievement in
    an urban middle school},
  journal = {Psychology in the Schools},
  year = {2006},
  volume = {43},
  pages = {701--712},
  number = {6}
}
```

```
\documentclass[man]{apa7}
\usepackage{lipsum, authblk}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[style=apa,sortcites=true,sorting=nyt,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: `biblatex-apa` implements 7th edition APA style. The rules for citations have slightly changed between 6th and 7th edition. In 7th edition APA style first and subsequent citation to the same work look the same no matter how many authors there are. For a work with three authors "First et al." is the expected output. Cf. https://apastyle.apa.org/style-grammar-guidelines/references/examples/journal-article-references.

Comment: What you describe is 6th edition APA style, which you can load with `style=apa6,`.

Comment: Note that independent of the issue you won't need `\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}` with a modern TeX system (and in fact it could be harmful, so I suggest you remove it). You also won't need `sortcites=true,sorting=nyt,`. Again `sorting=nyt,` could actually be harmful since it selects a different sorting scheme than the scheme selected by `style=apa`.

Comment: Thank you @moewe! They come with the template and removing those didn't affect my output.

Answer (score 3):

[I'm providing this answer just so that the posting can be considered to have received an "official" answer.]

The desired citation call-out behavior you describe is that of the 6th ed. of the APA manual. (What's current is the 7th ed.) To get the desired behavior with `biblatex` and `biber`, run

```
\usepackage[style=apa6]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}
```

in the preamble along with `\parencite` in the body of the document. If, for some reason, you would rather use the `apacite` package, you should run

```
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
```

in the preamble along with `\citep` in the body of the document.

[image]

```
\documentclass[man]{apa7}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{bibliography.bib}
@ARTICLE{Lassen2006,
  author  = {Lassen, Stephen R. and Steele, Michael M. and Sailor, Wayne},
  title   = {The relationship of school-wide positive behavior support 
             to academic achievement in an urban middle school},
  journal = {Psychology in the Schools},
  year    = {2006},
  volume  = {43},
  pages   = {701--712},
  number  = {6}
}
\end{filecontents}

%% With biblatex (and biber):
\usepackage[style=apa6]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

%% With apacite (and BibTeX):
%\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
%\bibliographystyle{apacite}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum, authblk}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[english=american]{csquotes}
\shorttitle{xyz} % just to suppress a pesky warning message
\hypersetup{colorlinks,allcolors=blue} % optional

\begin{document}

%% With biblatex (and biber):
\parencite{Lassen2006}, \parencite{Lassen2006}
\printbibliography

%% With apacite (and BibTeX):
%\citep{Lassen2006}, \citep{Lassen2006}
%\bibliography{bibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is very clear and works great for me! Thank you so much. Yes I was looking for APA6 citation style while my draft has already been created using the apa7 template.